# Javascript "extending" a method in a sub-object or subclass

Tags: javascript, object, extending

My goal is to have a widget object and have specific widgets extend that object. I would like to prevent people from having to call the render callback explicitly in every widget definition by somehow extending it in the parent (Widget). What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
 var Widget = function (options) {

    // super class

    if (this.constructor === Widget) {
        throw new Error("You can't instantiate abstract class.");
    }

    var widget = this.__proto__;

    Widget.renderCallBack = function(){
        //alert('the widget has rendered');
    }

    this.render = (function(){
        var _render = this.render;

        return function(){
            _render();
            Widget.renderCallBack();
        }

    })


}
Widget.constructor = Widget;


var SpecialWidget = function(options) {
    Widget.apply(this, arguments);
}

SpecialWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget);
SpecialWidget.constructor = SpecialWidget

SpecialWidget.prototype.render = function(){
    // render something
}

new SpecialWidget(options);
```

Comment: I would pass in the renderCallback as an option for SpecialWidget and set it's render method to call it. __var sw = new SpecialWidget({renderCallback: function(){}});__

Comment: That would work but I'm trying to abstract this "callback" into the Widget object because I want all "special widgets" to have a render function, and I want the same thing to happen after every render function runs without having to explicitly code that into each one. Is this possible / a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment: If it is the same for all it doesn't have to be a callback  function, just put the code to the end of the `render` method if it's job is synchronous, if not use a promise but you have to think about that of method shadowing you will overwrite the parent class' `render` method in the child. To avoid this you can use different name for the methods and call the parent's method from the child or use ES2015 class which has the `super` keyword for reaching the parent class' methods.

Also you had a typo in your code:

```
SpecialWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget);
```

It has to be:

```
SpecialWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype);
```

Anyway I don't think it is a good idea in general.

```js
var Widget = function(options) {
  this.options = options || {};
};

Widget.prototype.widgetRender = function() {
  // do stuff
  console.log('Widget render');
  // callback functionality
  console.log('Widget render callback functionality');
};
Widget.constructor = Widget;


var SpecialWidget = function(options) {
  Widget.apply(this, arguments);
};

SpecialWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype);
SpecialWidget.prototype.render = function() {
  // parent's render
  this.widgetRender();
  // do stuff
  console.log('SpecialWidget render');
  // callback functionality
  console.log('SpecialWidget render callback functionality');
};
SpecialWidget.constructor = SpecialWidget

var sw = new SpecialWidget();
sw.render();

// ES2015

class ES6Widget {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }
  render() {
    // do stuff
    console.log('ES6Widget render');
    // callback functionality
    console.log('ES6Widget render callback functionality');
  }
}

class ES6SpecialWidget extends ES6Widget {
  render() {
    // parent's render
    super.render();
    // do stuff
    console.log('ES6SpecialWidget render');
    // callback functionality
    console.log('ES6SpecialWidget render callback functionality');
  }
}


const es6sw = new ES6SpecialWidget();
es6sw.render();
```